# What is the notation for the set of the functions $f(t,r,z)$ that is smooth in $r$, $C^1$ in $t$ and $C^2$ in $z$?

Tags: notation, smooth-functions

In cylindrical coordinates $x=\{r,\theta,z\}$, let the axi-symmetrical scalar function $f(t,r,z)$ be $C^1$ in $t\in [0,\infty)=\mathbb{R}_0^+$, smooth ($C^\infty$) in $r\in [0,\infty)=\mathbb{R}_0^+$, and $C^2$ in $z\in \mathbb{R}$.
What is the symbol of the set that $f(t,r,z)$ belongs to?

Can we write as follows?
$$f(t,r,z)\in C^1(\mathbb{R}_0^+)C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_0^+)C^2(\mathbb{R})\tag{1}$$
or
$$f(t,r,z)\in C^1(t\in\mathbb{R}_0^+)C^\infty(r\in\mathbb{R}_0^+)C^2(z\in\mathbb{R})\tag{1}$$

Comment: There is no standard notation for this. It is too specialized a need for one to develop and spread. For those cases where different levels of differentiation are needed for each variable, it is usually explained verbally, as in your first paragraph. If you need to do this repeatedly in a document, you can introduce your own notation and use it. But you should introduce it again in any additional documents you put out (unless they are intended as follow-ups, where readers are expected to have read the original as well.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!